# Django 3 - How can I dynamically load choices of a CharField in a CBV from another table (foreign key)?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

A user creates one or more objects of class **VO**. Afterwards, they might want to add one or more **VE** to one VO. I tried to realize this with Class Based Views (CBVs).

`models.py`:

```
class VE(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False)
    vo = models.ForeignKey(VO, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class VO(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(_("Description"), max_length=255, blank=False)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

How can I now make sure that the CreateView for VE has a dropdown/previously filled out field for **VO**? To be more specific, I want the user to only select a VO which he owns (self.request.user == owner).
Is this at all possible with CBVs in Django 3 or do I have to create a custom method which uses `render()`?

I hope I formulated that question somewhat understandable. If not, please let me know and I'll provide additional needed information.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question here since I found the answer elsewhere.

Looks like it's not possible to realize this with CBVs, one needs to utilize `render` as initially suspected. Here is a short [blog post](https://web.archive.org/web/20190119094110/https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/questions/2017/03/22/how-to-dynamically-filter-modelchoices-queryset-in-a-modelform.html) on how to achieve this.